# hibernate ManyToMany Map<String, Entity> where map key is a property referenced via FK

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I'm working on a tricky many to many mapping that I want represented in my entity as a map.  The catch, is that I want the map key to be a column from one of the associated tables and not a column of the mapping table as is typically the case.

Account holds basic information about a user, AccountMetadata defines all the possible attributes an account may have, and Account_MetadataAccount defines a specific account's values for each possible AccountMetadata.

I've mapped these to the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
  private Long accountId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pk.account")
  private Set<AccountMetadataAccount> metadata = new HashSet<AccountMetadataAccount>();
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT_METADATA")
public class AccountMetadata implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_METADATA_ID")
  private Long accountMetadataId;

  @Column(name = "KEY", unique = true)
  private String key;

  @Column(name = "TYPE")
  private Class<?> type;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT_METADATA_ACCOUNT")
@AssociationOverrides({
                @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.account",
                  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")),
                @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.metadata",
                  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_METADATA_ID"))
              })
public class AccountMetadataAccount implements Serializable
{
  @EmbeddedId
  private AccountMetadataAccountId pk;

  @Column(name = "VALUE")
  private Serializable value;
...
}

@Embeddable
public class AccountMetadataAccountId implements Serializable
{
  @ManyToOne
  private AccountInfo account;

  @ManyToOne
  private AccountMetadataInfo metadata;
...
}
```

This all works great.  My problem, is the Account's metadata Set.  This isn't ideal.  If I've got a metadata key I want to look up a value for, I've got to iterate over the entire Set until I find the correct entry.  In our system, there could be hundreds of these.  I thought a `Map<String, AccountMetadataAccount>` or `Map<String, Serializable>` would be more ideal.  However, I'd want the map key to be the AccountMetadata key.

I've been experimenting with `@MapKeyColumn` and `@MapKeyJoinColumn` with no luck.  I can only find examples where the map key is derived from a column of the join table.

I'm hoping someone out there has done something similar, or at least has some words of wisdom on how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using getter and setter instead of a member variable? Like this:

```
@Transient
private Map<String, AccountMetadataAccount> metadata = new HashMap<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pk.account")
private Collection<AccountMetadataAccount> getMetadata() {
  return metadata.values();
}

private void setMetadata(Collection<AccountMetadataAccount> metaSet) {
   metadata.clear();
   for (AccountMetadataAccount meta : metaSet) {
     metadata.put(meta.key, meta);
   }
}
```

I use xml mapping files instead of annotations, and I didn't test the code anyway, so it might not be 100% correct, but you should catch the idea.